# RNEncryptedStorage is undefined in react-native-web

Tags: ios, react-native, react-native-web

I'm developing ios and web app. For storing credentials using encrypted storage, and in web I'm using local storage for now.
But at the time of compiling web app throws error.

```
rnw_blogpost.bundle.js:5540 Uncaught Error: RNEncryptedStorage is
undefined at eval (EncryptedStorage.js:1:862) at
Object../node_modules/react-native-encrypted-storage/lib/module/EncryptedStorage.js (rnw_blogpost.bundle.js:1766:1) at __webpack_require__
(rnw_blogpost.bundle.js:5537:33) at fn
(rnw_blogpost.bundle.js:5736:21) at eval (index.js:1:389) at
Object../node_modules/react-native-encrypted-storage/lib/module/index.js
(rnw_blogpost.bundle.js:1776:1) at __webpack_require__
(rnw_blogpost.bundle.js:5537:33) at fn
(rnw_blogpost.bundle.js:5736:21) at eval (encrypted-storage.ts:1:565)
at Object../src/util/encrypted-storage.ts
(rnw_blogpost.bundle.js:4098:1)
```

This is due to https://github.com/emeraldsanto/react-native-encrypted-storage/blob/master/src/EncryptedStorage.ts#L7

Is there any way, that in web I can handle it.

Answer (score 0):

Looks to me like this might be a keychain permissions issue – the error in the source code doesn't show *what* is happening, but it looks like the system isn't able to import `RNEncryptedStorage` at all. Other possibility is that it may just be a missing dependency – have you tried `pod install`?

Comment: Yes, I have done pod install. Infact it is working fine in IOS, but same code is being run on web. As in web RNEncryptedStorage doesn't exist, it throws error in compilation time.

Comment: Are you testing in Safari?

Comment: No on chrome. I'm using react-native-web for running same code base in web browser.

Comment: Could be it then. Try Safari?